# SQL Partition Elimination

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, partitioning

I am currently testing a partitioning configuration, using actual execution plan to identify RunTimePartitionSummary/PartitionsAccessed info.

When a query is run with a literal against the partitioning column the partition elimination works fine (using = and <=). However if the query is joined to a lookup table, with the partitioning column <= to a column in the lookup table and restricting the lookup table with another criteria (so that only one row is returned, the same as if it was a literal) elimination does not occur.

This only seems to happen if the join criteria is <= rather than =, even though the result is the same. Reversing the logic and using between does not work either, nor does using a cross applied function.

**Edit: (Repro Steps)**

OK here you go!

```
--Create sample function
CREATE PARTITION FUNCTION pf_Test(date) AS RANGE RIGHT FOR VALUES ('20110101','20110102','20110103','20110104','20110105') 
--Create sample scheme
CREATE PARTITION SCHEME ps_Test AS PARTITION pf_Test ALL TO ([PRIMARY])
--Create sample table
CREATE TABLE t_Test
    (
        RowID int identity(1,1)
        ,StartDate date NOT NULL
        ,EndDate date NULL
        ,Data varchar(50) NULL
    )
ON ps_Test(StartDate)
--Insert some sample data
INSERT INTO t_Test(StartDate,EndDate,Data)
VALUES
    ('20110101','20110102','A')
    ,('20110103','20110104','A')
    ,('20110105',NULL,'A')
    ,('20110101',NULL,'B')
    ,('20110102','20110104','C')
    ,('20110105',NULL,'C')
    ,('20110104',NULL,'D')

--Check partition allocation
SELECT *,$PARTITION.pf_Test(StartDate) AS PartitionNumber FROM t_Test

--Run simple test (inlcude actual execution plan)
SELECT 
    *
    ,$PARTITION.pf_Test(StartDate)
FROM t_Test
WHERE StartDate <= '20110103' AND ISNULL(EndDate,getdate()) >= '20110103'
--<PartitionRange Start="1" End="4" />

--Run test with join to a lookup (with CTE for simplicity, but doesnt work with table either)
WITH testCTE AS
    (
        SELECT convert(date,'20110101') AS CalendarDate,'A' AS SomethingInteresting
        UNION ALL
        SELECT convert(date,'20110102') AS CalendarDate,'B' AS SomethingInteresting
        UNION ALL
        SELECT convert(date,'20110103') AS CalendarDate,'C' AS SomethingInteresting
        UNION ALL
        SELECT convert(date,'20110104') AS CalendarDate,'D' AS SomethingInteresting
        UNION ALL
        SELECT convert(date,'20110105') AS CalendarDate,'E' AS SomethingInteresting
        UNION ALL
        SELECT convert(date,'20110106') AS CalendarDate,'F' AS SomethingInteresting
        UNION ALL
        SELECT convert(date,'20110107') AS CalendarDate,'G' AS SomethingInteresting
        UNION ALL
        SELECT convert(date,'20110108') AS CalendarDate,'H' AS SomethingInteresting
        UNION ALL
        SELECT convert(date,'20110109') AS CalendarDate,'I' AS SomethingInteresting
    )

SELECT
    C.CalendarDate
    ,T.*
    ,$PARTITION.pf_Test(StartDate)
FROM t_Test T
    INNER JOIN testCTE C
        ON T.StartDate <= C.CalendarDate AND ISNULL(T.EndDate,getdate()) >= C.CalendarDate
WHERE C.SomethingInteresting = 'C'    --<PartitionRange Start="1" End="6" />

--So all 6 partitions are scanned despite only 2,3,4 being required, as per the simple select.
```

--edited to make resultant ranges identical to ensure fair test

Comment: Please state version of SQL Server

Comment: +1 more explicitly what is `SELECT @@VERSION;` as several fixes for partitioning issues have been released in SPs/Cumulative Updates.

Comment: I've added this information into the question tags. Wouldn't hurt to add some code that repros this issue either...

Answer (score 0):

It makes sense for the query to scan all the partitions.

All partitions are involved in the predicate `T.StartDate <= C.CalendarDate`, because the query planner can't possibly know which values `C.CalendarDate` might take.